# React-native run-ios não funciona mas o Xcode sim

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, xcode, mac

Eu criei um projeto RN 0.59 onde estava tudo funcionando.
Após a instalação das bibliotecas o comando

```
react-native run-ios
```

parou de funcionar. O simulador abre a aplicação, permanecendo na tela de splash por um tempo, e fechando o app em seguida.

Porem se eu abro o projeto no Xcode, e mando executar, ele abre normalmente.

Alguém sabe o pq?

Comment: experimente: matar o processo da porta:
`lsof -n -i4TCP:8081 | sed '1 d' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`e resetar o cache:

`reactive-native start --  --reset-cache`

Comment: Vc instalou os Pods? Entra na pasta ios/ e executa:  `pod install`

Comment: eu estou usando a v 0.59 do RN. o pod install retorna isso:
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Comment: nada ainda, continua crashado e o Metro congelado em Loading dependency graph, done.

Comment: Vc precisa adicionar o Podfile na pasta, instala o cocoapods, está usando yarn: `yarn add cocoapods` ou npm: `npm i cocoapods`

Comment: [veja aqui como fazer](https://medium.com/@soufianerafik/how-to-add-pods-to-an-xcode-project-2994aa2abbf1).

Comment: obs: para executar no Android, não esqueça de criar um arquivo na raiz da pasta do android: `local.properties`,  escrito dentro:  `sdk.dir = /Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk `ele deve estar apontando para o diretório do seu sdk 8 instalado na máquina, e o emulador deve estar aberto.

Comment: Eu estava usando somente o react-native link, ate então estava funcionando, nunca precisei do cocoapods. Sei que a versão 0.60 exige o cocoa, mas a 0.59 não

Comment: Dá uma [olhada aqui](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios), dá pra fazer manualmente se quiser.